# WCF InstanceContextMode.PerCall Services and Multi-Threading

Tags: multithreading, wcf, windows-services

I am running a self-hosted WCF Service (it will be a Windows Service but I'm runnning it as a Console App for debugging). The server side code needs to do some work when it is called. Then pass  back the result synchronously to the client. It then needs to carry on and do some more intensive long-running processing.(ie asynchronously)

A simplified illustration of the code is :

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true,InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class MyWCFService : IMyWCFService, IDisposable {

    private Thread importThread;
    private DoWork importWork;


    public MyImportResultContract StartImport(MyImportRequestContract requestParams) {

            processorResult = new MyImportResultContract();


        //Simulate a short piece of work here to return results to the 
        //caller before calling a Thread to do more processing
    processorResult.Success = true;
    processorResult.Messages = "A message to pass back to caller"


            Console.WriteLine("WCF Class ManagedThreadId = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);


    //Thread off to do long running process
            importWork = new DoWork();               
            importThread  = new Thread(importWork.Start);
            importThread.Start();

            //Pass back the results
            return processorResult; 
    }


public void Dispose() {

        Console.WriteLine("WCF Class Dispose : " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }

}


internal class DoWork : IDisposable {

     public void Start() {

    Console.WriteLine("Thread ManagedThreadId = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

   //Simulate a long running process
       Thread.Sleep(60000);

        Console.WriteLine("Thread Finished");            
    }


    public void Dispose() {

        Console.WriteLine("DoWork Class Dispose : " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }


}
```

**I have 2 questions:**
1. I'm seeing the Dispose of the Service Class called before the Thread it spawns carries on and completes. My concern is that the Service class instance might not be getting released for Garbage collection because of the thread it spawns. Is the code outlined here solid so that this won't happen?
2. The service is self hosted in a Windows Service. What will happen if the service is stopped to any spawned threads ? Is there a way to get the service to wait until any Threads still running complete ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Of course the service class can be disposed before the thread completes. If you wanted to wait for the work in the thread to complete, why start a thread? I'm not sure what behavior you expect/want other than this.
2. Yes, if the process is shut down your threads die. You have to implement a handler for the service stop callback which delays the shutdown process until all workers are complete. This will be easier to do if you use the more modern `Task` instead of `Thread`. Probably, you need to keep a global list of tasks in process so that your shutdown code can `WaitAll` on those tasks.